# How to get error information in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm building an API in `Laravel`, but if I have an error I just get a `500` response with no extended information.
Laravel also no longer seems to be writing anything to the `laravel.log` file.

My `.env` has:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

What's the best way to find out why errors are occurring, without relying on HTML-generated response pages?

Comment: What server are you using? and is the option "debug" in config/app.php set to something?

Comment: Probably because you're debugging JSON, if you're using Chrome and you go to Network tools, you can link the requests in red and select `preview` tab in order to see the HTML generated page for that error. That's the only way if you don't want to use a tool like Postman

Comment: What is the value of 'log' variable in config/app.php? By default it's 'single' which writes to laravel.log file (Laravel 5).

Comment: @Frondor Preview and Response are both empty in Network tab when I get an error. ALL I get is a 500 coded response with no error information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what is happening is that a constructor is failing somewhere.  Either the constructor for the request object (because you have used validation in a custom request class) or a constructor for one of the API controller classes or a dependency injected class.

Fir the first issue - I would advise against custom request classes and do the validation manually once your API function is entered.

For the second issue you may have to do some specific error logging in the constructors of your controller class and the classes that get injected in there as dependencies.  There is a top level exception handler class and you can also try doing some logging in there: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#the-exception-handler

Comment: I finally found the problem via running `php artisan tail` - there was an error in my Handler.php of all places...

Comment: And now THAT isn't working - I'm getting `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "tail" is not defined.` You know, I absolutely love Laravel :o/

Comment: I love Laravel too but I hate its error handling.  :P